# SQL Insert Into a MAX value

Tags: mysql, sql

In SQL how would I insert into a MAX count of another column

So I have this

```
INSERT INTO USER(id,name,employee_code,email) VALUES (3,john,(SELECT MAX(employee_code)+1 FROM USER),"john@example.com");
```

However this doesn't work with the syntax... basically it's like an autoincrement that I have to self build because the employee_code sometimes equals 0 for temporary employees so I need a command to take the max code in their and add one.

Comment: Please run `SHOW CREATE TABLE USER\G` and post it.

Comment: If you have multiple users of your database/application you need to handle this differently by explicit locking or by using a sequence-derived or autoincrement value for employee code depending on what your rdbms provides.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do away with the VALUES statement and use a select instead:

```
INSERT INTO USER(id,name,employee_code,email)
    SELECT 3, 'john', MAX(employee_code)+1, "john@example.com"
    FROM USER
```

Comment: actually they are there I forgot to add them in on here... sorry

Answer (score 4):

You probably forgot quotes around `john`:

```
INSERT INTO USER(id,name,employee_code,email)
VALUES (3, 'john', (SELECT MAX(employee_code)+1 FROM `USER`), "john@example.com");
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use an `INSERT INTO... SELECT ...FROM` query:

```
INSERT INTO USER(id,name,employee_code,email) 
SELECT 3, 'john', MAX(employee_code)+1, 'john@example.com'
FROM `USER`;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO USER(id,name,employee_code,email) 

SELECT 
   3,
   'john', 
   MAX(employee_code)+1, 
   'john@example.com' 
FROM USER
```